# Extend forms authentication timeout dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, timeout, forms-authentication

I am not sure how that forms authentication. But I assume it just creates cookie based on forms authentication timeout.

So given that I am trying to increase forms auth cookie expiration based on some headers sent to server. For that I disabled `slidingExpiration` in order to calculate expiration on my own.

In `Application_BeginRequest` I am doing:

```
if (!bypassSlidingExpiration)
{
    var authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
    authCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(FormsAuthentication.Timeout.TotalMinutes);
    Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
}
```

But regardless of `bypassSlidingExpiration` my session expired after `FormsAuthentication.Timeout`.

What I am going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing the other code branch? It looks like you're only handling the case where  `bypassSlidingExpiration` is false. If `bypassSlidingExpiration` is true, then you're taking the default value (30 minutes, or whatever's specified in the web.config or programmatically).

You could consider using `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true)` to bypass the sliding expiration. The second parameter is whether the cookie should be persistent. It's probably best to avoid manipulating the cookie manually. If you for some reason you must, something like this might work:

```
if (bypassSlidingExpiration)
{
    var authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
    authCookie.Expires = DateTime.MaxValue;
    Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that works very strange authCookie.Expires in ALL cases  01/01/0001 00:00:00 but I am setting that to value that I want at Application_EndRequest and it returns to browser correct value. However I have cases what I don't need to extend expiry time but in those cases cookie extended every 30 seconds

Comment: @Vladimirs try adding the updated cookie to the response rather than the request. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: I update question. After some attempts to achieve that I found and replaced it in my code (but forgot to update question) however it still doesn't works as expected. Best I could do it is all the time assign some value to Expires field, because sometimes it was overridden somewhere. And proper date I could get only when after I decrypted that ticket.